# Syntax Errors while making a Python If/Elif/Else program to display roman numeral equivalent of input

Tags: python

Edit: Rather than vote me down can you provide an url on where you would recommend a newbie learn Python? Be part of the solution versus problem.

I'm trying to compile a basic program (for a class) that when specific if/elif/else conditions are met a specific roman numeral shows though I'm a bit confused on why I'm getting my error. Error included next.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 42
    print"The number is I"
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I remove the else line altogether the program operates but I don't ever get any of the if/elif functions of print to actually print out. I've been going off of this below tutorial for learning the else/if python as the community college doesnt teach python but frustratingly enough asks projects be coded in it.

tutorial:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

which I've learned I need to put whatever I want printed in paranthesis
correct: print ("1 - Got a false expression value")
wrong: print "1 - Got a false expression value"

Again I'm lost on this error - any advice or direction to a tutorial where I can understand this would be much appreciated

```
# ////////////////////// ALGORITHIM /////////////////////////
# 1 prompt the user for a number from range of 1-10
# 2 display roman numeral for that number
# 3 if outside range of 1-10 display error message invalid number try reentering
# ////////////////////// ALGORITHIM END /////////////////////////
# ////////////////////// PSEUDOCODE /////////////////////////
# IF <<number >= 0, 11
#    Error the number you have entered is not in the range of 1-10
# Elif var = 1
#   display I
# Elif var = 2
#   display II
# Elif var = 2
#   display II
# Elif var = 3
#   display III
# Elif var = 4
#   display IV
# Elif var = 5
#   display V
# Elif var = 6
#   display VI
# Elif var = 7
#   display VII
# Elif var = 8
#   display VIII
# Elif var = 9
#   display IX
# Elif var = 10
#   display X
#END IF

# MAIN MODULE
number = 0

#getInput Module
number = input(int("Please enter a number within the range of 1-10"))
print("Was your number " + number  + "?")

#decisionPiece Module
if(number==1):
    print"The number is I"
elif(number==2):
    print"The number is II"
elif(number==3):
    print"The nubmer is III"
elif(number==4):
    print"The nubmer is IV"
elif(number==5):
    print"The nubmer is V"
elif(number==6):
    print"The nubmer is VI"
elif(number==7):
    print"The nubmer is VII"
elif(number==8):
    print"The nubmer is VIII"
elif(number==9):
    print"The nubmer is IX"
elif(number==10):
    print"The nubmer is X"
else:
    print"The number you entered is not within the range of 1-10"

print ("Good bye!")    
#printNumber Module
```

Comment: `else` doesn't take a condition..

Comment: Your code is not going to work the way you think it will work, anyway. Assuming you're using Python 3, `input()` returns a string, which you would need to explicitly cast to an `int` before comparing it with other ints.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer MattDMo I will correct this. I apparently wasn't following the tutorial I found as closely as I should have been.

I'm going to have to study up on this int matter though because I don't understand that. Again there isn't any education provided on python for the course we're just expected to learn it on top of our class Programming Logic & Design. Do you have any recommendations on up to date material on this int process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
number = input(int("Please enter a number within the range of 1-10"))
```

is now giving you problems.  You need get the input, then convert to an int:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number within the range of 1-10"))
```

This code will still throw an error if the user enters anything that it cannot convert to an int.  I'm guessing that they are not looking for you to trap that condition for this project.

Comment: Thank you very much Alan I finally found a python 3.x tutorial for input/float which is enlightening. I'm not used to this after learning html/css. Oy.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Who_Goes_There%3F

What do you mean by trap that condition? The project is just to have it respond to numerical answers or if there is a number outside 1-10 input to have an output of an error which I now know I need to put into the else clause.

Comment: After reviewing that tutorial and your suggestions I get that I have to essentially be telling the program to classify the type of input that the input is/is supposed to be/expected to be. 

I made your recommended changes which resulted in the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 38, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

so due to this error i removed the following line that was on line 38 previously. I was previously using this to test/verify that the program was seeing/getting input
print("Was your number " + number  + "?")

Comment: Ah ha i figured out...i think part of the answer to your question. It would be combining string/float/int values in a print via commas. For example my previously removed line on line 38 i could do this. print("Was your number ", number, "?") instead of the + signs.

Comment: @L2g2h Yeah, that will work.  It can be cleaner to do that as: `print ("Was your number %d?"%number)`

Answer (score 2):

```
else(number==3):
    print("The number is X")
```

Is incorret. You should use only

```
else :
    print("The number is X")
```

Comment: Doh I was apparrently not fully paying attention to the tutorial that I referenced as it also doesn't reference putting a condition on the else. Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `else:` instead of `else(number==3)`. `else:` doesn't take a condition. Also, you don't need to put parentheses around the conditions in Python.